# symmetric AES enryption concept

Tags: encryption, aes

i have a project for a website, running on Django. One function of it needs to store user/password for a third party website. So it needs to be symmetric encryption, as it needs to use these credentials in an automated process. 
Storing credentials is never a good idea, I know, but for this case there is no other option.
My idea so far is, to create a Django app, that will save and use these passwords, and do nothing else. With this I can have 2 "webservers" that will not receive any request from outside, but only get tasking via redis or something. Therefore I can isolate them to some degree (they are the only servers who will have access to this extra db, they will not handle any web request, etc)
First question: Does this plan sound solid or is there a major flaw?

Second question is about the encryption itself:
AES requires an encryption key for all its work, ok that needs to be "secured" in some way. But I am more interested in the IV. 
Every user can have one or more credential sets saved in the extra db. Would it be a good idea to use some hash of sort over the user id or something to generate a per user custom IV? Most of the time I see IV to be just random generated. But then I will have to also store them somewhere in addition to the key.
For me it gets a bit confusing here. I need key and IV to decrypt, but I would "store" them the same way. So wouldn't it be likely if one get compromised, that also the IV will be? Would it then make any difference if I generate the IV on the fly over a known procedure? Problem then, everyone could know the IV if they know their user id, as the code will be open source....

In the end, I need some direction guidance as how to handle key and best unique IV per user. Thank you very much for reading so far :-)

Comment: `user/password for a third party website` - are those service credentials for your application or you ask users to store their user credentials for an external app? (to do something on their behalf? This is what OAuth is used for)

Comment: The credentials are for an external app. But oauth needs to be implemented on the external app, right? And that is my problem, this external app does not provide any api or token based authentification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this plan sound solid or is there a major flaw?

The need to store use credentials is imho a flaw by design, at least we all appreciate you are aware of it.

Having a separate *credential service* with dedicated datastore seems to be best you can do under stated conditions. I don't like the option to store user credentials, but let's skip academic discussion to practical things.

> AES requires an encryption key for all its work, ok that needs to be "secured" in some way.

Yes, there's the whole problem.

> to generate a per user custom IV?

IV allows reusing the same key for multiple encryptions, so effectively it needs to be unique for each ciphertext (if a user has multiple passwords, you need an IV for each password). Very commonly IV is prepended to the ciphertext as it is needed to decrypt it.

> Would it then make any difference if I generate the IV on the fly over a known procedure?

IV doesn't need to be secret itself.

Some encryption modes require the IV to be unpredictable (e.g. CBC mode), therefore it's best if you generate the IV as random. There are some modes that use IV as a counter to encrypt/decrypt only part of data (such as CTR or OFB), but still it is required the IV is unique for each key and encryption.

Comment: Thank you, that is some helpful feedback. And yes it is flawed by having to store them. But this feature will be voluntary and shall have the appropriate warnings for the user. The third party just does not provide any sort of api or oatuh. Now I have to figure out how to store the IV's... and nothing makes sense... storing them on the db, would be like not using them at all (here is the encrypted string and the IV for it!), storing on disk does not work for my setup, everything else is volatile :-/